# Using :is in nested CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am really confused about the behavior of `:is` in my nested CSS. In the following minimal example –

```css
th, td { border: solid #000 1px; }
th { font-style: italic; }

div table {
    & :is(th,td) {
        border: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```

```html
<table><tr> <th>Some text</th> <td>More text</td></tr></table>
<div><table><tr> <th>Some text</th> <td>More text</td></tr></table></div>
```

– the table cells of the table embedded in a division are formatted differently (as intended and expected).

But in my actual CSS, only the following variants #2 and #3 – where the `:is` selector is not nested within the table selector – work:

```
# 1
main form {
    & table {
        /* ... */
        & :is(th, td) {
            /* ... */
        }
    }

# 2
main form {
    & table {
        /* ... */
        & th, & td {
            /* ... */
        }
    }

# 3
main form {
    & table {
        /* ... */
    }
    & :is(th, td) {
        /* ... */
    }
```

Why would there be such a difference?